# Templated class where template parameters are used to define member functions

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Suppose I define a class like `pack` below (simplified for this question), where the constructor receives two callables and uses them as member functions:

```
#include <iostream>

struct callable1{
    void operator()(){
        std::cout << "callable 1\n";
    }
};
struct callable2{
    void operator()(){
        std::cout << "callable 2\n";
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class pack{
  public:
    pack(T1 t1, T2 t2): f1{t1}, f2{t2} {}
    T1 f1;
    T2 f2;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    pack<callable1, callable2> p{callable1{}, callable2{}};
    p.f1();
    p.f2();
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the following output

```bash
callable 1
callable 2
```

How would you generalize `pack` so that you can give its constructor an arbitrary number of callables, one or more, and it implements them as member functions? If the constructor receives two callables, like above, it would effectively produce the code and behaviors also shown above. Ideally without using macros.

---

Bonus: Instead of calling it like this

```
    p.f1();
    p.f2();
```

you'd be able to call it using the name or type of the object given to the constructor. For the callables used in the first code block above, instead, you'd be able to call the member functions of `p` as follows

```
    p.callable1();
    p.callable2();
```

Comment: It is totally unclear what you want. What should `auto p = pack([](){});` do?

Comment: @n.m. I guess given a free function `A foo()` OP wants to get a class `p` with `A p::foo()` member function via `p = pack(foo);`.

Comment: @Evg Your guess is as good as mine. I want a clarification. `[](){}` is a callable object. What should `auto p = pack([](){});` do? While we are at it, what should `auto q = pack(some::long::namespace::with::free::function)` do? What should `auto f = g; auto pf=pack(f); auto pg=pack(g);` do, will `pf` be different from `pg`?

Comment: @n.m. These are all very good questions.

Comment: @Evg, n.m. I have edited the question trying to clarify.

Comment: You can't do it with `f1()`-type syntax but it's [easy](https://godbolt.org/z/qe4fxG4dM) with `f<1>()`-type one.

Comment: There is no way to create an arbitrary number of members, but do you really need to? Your `pack` is essentially a `tuple`.